# Why is'nt this JavaScript function not redirecting to selected option value?

Tags: javascript, select

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function redirect(location) {
    window.location.href=location;
}
```

Which I'm using like so:

```
<select onChange="redirect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="http://mysite.com/videos">One</option>
<option value="http://mysite.com/music">Two</option>
</select>
```

I'm expecting for it to redirect to the selected option value, but does'nt seem to do anything? - bare in mind im new to JavaScript.

Hope someone can help! :)

Comment: well - i tried your code on Chrome and FF, and it seems to be working fine. which browser are you trying on? and i hope there are no typos in the code you're testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select onChange="redirect(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
function redirect() {
    var location=document.getElementById("i").value;
    window.location.href=location;
}

</script>
<select onChange="redirect()" id="i">
<option value="http://mysite.com/videos">One</option>
<option value="http://mysite.com/music">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself is functional (i tried).

Where have you placed the function definition?
Is there any other javascript code on the page?

In which browser are you testing this?
If you're running it in Firefox check the error console (Tools->error console).

I also noticed that Internet Explorer 8 blocks this javascript, I haD to check allow blocked content for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

can be because `location` is a short way to call `window.location`, so just rename your input parameter - `_location`, `newLocation`, `loc`, whatever else.

**UPDATE**

Nope, this should work. Having only

```
<select onChange="redirect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="http://mysite.com/videos">One</option>
<option value="http://mysite.com/music">Two</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(location) {
    window.location.href=location;
}
</script>
```

on the page gave me the desired result, so the error may be somewhere around - just give us more code!